# Cannot load openssl even after reinstalling with rvm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, rvm

So I basically get this:

```
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:22:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
    from /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/https.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activeresource-3.2.12/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:4:in `require'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activeresource-3.2.12/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activeresource-3.2.12/lib/active_resource/base.rb:15:in `require'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activeresource-3.2.12/lib/active_resource/base.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/cached_resource-2.3.3/lib/cached_resource.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/bundler-1.3.0/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Even after doing:

```
$ rvm pkg install openssl
$ rvm remove 1.9.3
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

I also have this in my `.zhsrc` file:

```
[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

This happens when I try tuse any `rails` or `rake` command on my project directory. I tried so many things I still can't find the way to get through it.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just in case: are you sure zsh is running and not bash?

Comment: @BenjaminSullivan Absolutely :(